# opencv cvblob render issue

Tags: c++, opencv

I just installed cvblob for object detection.

When I tried to run the program, the image would not show up and it gives me an error:
"VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument"

Here is the code.

```
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "cvaux.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include <cvblob.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace cvb;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    CvTracks tracks;

    namedWindow("frame", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvMoveWindow("frame", 50, 100);

    CvCapture* capture;

    IplImage* frame = 0;

//    frame = cvLoadImage("fruits.jpg", 1);

    capture = cvCreateCameraCapture( 1 ); //capture frames from cam on index 0: /dev/video0/

    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 240);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 320);

    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

    while(capture) {
        IplImage *gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
        cvCvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvThreshold(gray, gray, 150, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        IplImage *labelImg=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(gray), IPL_DEPTH_LABEL, 1);
        CvBlobs blobs;
        unsigned int result=cvLabel(gray, labelImg, blobs);

        cvFilterByArea(blobs, 500, 1000000);
        cvRenderBlobs(labelImg, blobs, frame, frame, CV_BLOB_RENDER_BOUNDING_BOX);
        cvUpdateTracks(blobs, tracks, 200., 5);
        cvRenderTracks(tracks, frame, frame, CV_TRACK_RENDER_ID|CV_TRACK_RENDER_BOUNDING_BOX);

//        for (CvBlobs::const_iterator it=blobs.begin(); it!=blobs.end(); ++it) {
//            cout << "Blob #" << it->second->label << ": Area=" << it->second->area << ", Centroid=(" << it->second->centroid.x << ", " << it->second->centroid.y << ")" << endl;
//        }

        cvShowImage("frame", frame);

        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the commented part, the blob information will be shown.

Can anyone help me find out why the image is not showing?

Thanks,
Milo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is coming from the video capture system, not cvBlob.

I see a few issues:

1. You must test `capture` after creating it to make sure you have successfully opened a camera.
2. Your `while` loop should be testing `frame`, not `capture` to make sure you've successfully received a frame of video.
3. Are you sure you have a camera at index 1?

Try this simplified version and see if it works. Note that I'm testing `capture`, looping while `frame` is not 0, and opening the camera at index 0. This works on my system.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    namedWindow("frame", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvMoveWindow("frame", 50, 100);

    CvCapture* capture;

    IplImage* frame = 0;

    capture = cvCreateCameraCapture( 0 ); //capture frames from cam on index 0: /dev/video0/
    if (!capture) {
        return -1;
    }

    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 240);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 320);

    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

    while(frame) {
        cvShowImage("frame", frame);

        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    }
}
```

If this works for you, try changing the `cvCreateCameraCapture` argument to 1. Then try adding back your code a little at a time.

Comment: I tried your code. Still, no image is shown. Then I tried to add "if(cvWaitKey(10)==27) break;". The image is finally shown. I wonder why it is not shown without this line. Anyway, your answer is accepted. Thanks.